# Blender 2.8 UV Does not appear?

Tags: uv

I'm having difficulty with this one. I've used UV unwrap on simple objects and texture painted them just fine. However I cannot get an unwrapped UV to show up in the editor on this model. I'm certain I'm missing something basic but my Google fu has ran out.

I've got everything selected, have used Project to View on this example but doesn't make a difference really. What am I missing? Any help gratefully received.

Am on Dec 26th build of Blender 2.8 but it's been like this for a while. May be nothing to do with it being 2.8 I realised.

[image]

Comment: It appears that you are doing everything right (they have recently split the UV and the Image editor, and you seem to be correctly using the former). The only thing I can suggest is doing "A" on the UV window, then ".", to rule out the entire UV map being out of the display limits

Comment: Thank you - nothing changed really. It bought up a pie menu and I tried the different options. For some mystery reason, it's not working on this model in this version. I'll try again on final release I think. I was only after making the mapped texture far more refined as it's pixelated on the transparent faces.

Comment: Oh sorry I meant to say "." from the numpad, not the one from the letter keyboard

Comment: can you share the file?

Comment: I think I gave up over the Xmas holiday. Sadly some roadblocks do knock me way off course for such a long time that I lose skills I had previously :( Which sucks badly.

Answer (score 8):

You need to hit **UV Sync Selection** (The 2 arrows)

[image: UV Sync Selection]

Comment: Thanks for that.  Worked great!

Answer (score 2):

You can trying to make a new Workspace

I had that problem with the OLD (2.79) files
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Change in the panel as shown in the image from View to Uv_Edit.
Good luck

Answer (score 1):

To get a UV image to display on an object in the 3D viewport I had to go to the materials tab, click the little circle button to the right of 'Base Color', select Image Texture then select the image I used in the UV.

[image: a screenshot of blender 2.8 beta showing the Image Texture option under Base Color on the material tab]

Answer (score 1):

Go to object dat properties panel, open the uv maps section and delete the current uv map. Then just create a new one. That fixed it for me .

Comment: For me, my UV map was missing, I parented an object to another one, and the parent UVmap got deleted somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem today and I found a solution for my case:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just change image editor to uv editor in the corner

Answer (score 0):

I had that issue today.  The UV was there, just not showing up properly in the editor or texture paint space.  It was just a simple wall so I marked seam on every edge and did a smart UV project.  It showed up perfectly and I could see there were some weird linkages between a couple of vertices that were not even connected on the object.  Good enough to work with though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running 3.6 and had this issue come up and it turned out to be there were 2 UV maps listed in the Data properties tab under UV Maps. I deleted both then unwrapped the object again and the object unwrapped properly.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem and nothing and no advice online helped, what I did was save the file I was working on , opened a new blender, append my job from previous and all worked again !